# how to listen to a specific port in qt using QTcpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, ubuntu

I'm using QTcpSocket to communicate between two applications. one is a c++ program and the other one is a web page written in PHP.

The goal is to send data from my webpage to my c++ program using sockets.

I don't know how to open a connection on a specific port e.g 12345 and listen to it if I got any data or not ..

I've written the following code so far:

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Mysocket = new QSocket(this);
    Mysocket->Initialization();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

QSocket.cpp

```
#include "qsocket.h"
#define SOCKET_PORT 12345
QSocket::QSocket(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}


void QSocket::Initialization()
{
    //connected
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost("localhost",SOCKET_PORT);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)),this,SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));
    if(!socket->waitForConnected(1000))
    {
        QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
        reply = QMessageBox::question(0,"Error","Error in Socket Connection",
                                        QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
        socket->close();
    }
    socket80->close();
}
void QSocket::connected()
{
        QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
        int PortNumber = socket->localPort();
        reply = QMessageBox::question(0,"Connected","Socket Connection is Established",
                                        QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);

        qDebug()<<"I'm Listening to Port: "<<PortNumber<<"on the local host \n";
}

void QSocket::disconnected()
{
    qDebug()<<"Disconnected .... \n";
    socket->close();
}

void QSocket::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)
{
        qDebug()<<"We wrote "<<bytes<<" \n";
}

void QSocket::readyRead()
{
    qDebug()<<"Reading .... \n";
    qDebug()<<socket->bytesAvailable();
    qDebug()<<socket->readAll();
}
```

When I run this code it doesn't open any connection and gives error and it enters into this if statement ..

```
if(!socket->waitForConnected(1000))
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply = QMessageBox::question(0,"Error","Error in Socket Connection",
                                    QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
    socket->close();
}
```

if I changed the port number to 80 it works fine and all the functions work properly.
By reading some posts in SO I've realized that a solution would be to use QTcpServer but I don't have any specific experience in it.
What's the problem in here ?!

P.S.

My Platform Specs.

Ubuntu 13.10

Qt 5.2.1

Comment: I think you need `QTcpServer` and its `QTcpServer::listen()` function. As soon as you get new connection the `newConnection` signal will be emitted and you need to handle it to create a new socket for data transfer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following sample server. You can start listening on a port by calling start_listen(int port_no).

```
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QMessageBox>

class server : public QTcpServer {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit server(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~server();
    QTcpSocket server_socket;
public slots:
    void tcpReady();
    void tcpError( QAbstractSocket::SocketError error );
    bool start_listen(int port_no);
protected:
    void incomingConnection( int descriptor );
};

server::server(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent) {
    connect( &server_socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(tcpError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)) );
    connect( &server_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
             this, SLOT(tcpReady()) );
    server_socket.setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, true );
}

server::~server() {
    server_socket.disconnectFromHost();
    server_socket.waitForDisconnected();
}

void server::tcpReady() {
    QByteArray array = server_socket.read(erver_socket.bytesAvailable());
}

void server::tcpError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error) {
    QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error"),tr("TCP error: %1").arg( server_socket.errorString() ) );
}

bool server::start_listen(int port_no) {
    if( !this->listen( QHostAddress::Any, port_no ) ) {
        QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Cannot listen to port %1").arg(port_no) );
    }
    else
        return true;
}

void server::incomingConnection(int descriptor) {
    if( !server_socket.setSocketDescriptor( descriptor ) ) {
        QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Socket error!") );
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: ..Thanks for your answer..I didn't test your code yet but isn't it necessary to open a connection on a port before listening to it ? we can listen to any port in general ? or I need to open that port in my c++ program before using it ?

Comment: if the answer is yes then how ? how can I open a port in qt for a qtcpserver object ?

Comment: By calling listen you are actually opening a port and listening on it waiting for someone to connect you. When someone connects the incomingConnection function is called and by calling setSocketDescriptor and passing the descriptor you make the connection and you can communicate through the QTCPSocket afterwards.

Comment: just one more thing .. if I start a connection using listen method, do I have to send something to my client before I could get anything or there's no need for that ? what's the specific function in qtcpserver to write sth on a port ?

Comment: When you call listen you should wait until the client side connects you which invokes incomingConnection. For writing data you should use the write method of your QTcpSocket object like: server_socket.write( someBytes );

Comment: but how your incomingConnection function is called !! I can't see how it's related to the main code ?!!

Comment: incomingConnection is a virtual function which is called by QTcpServer when a new connection is available. You reimplement this function to set the socket descriptor for the accepted connection.