# How to make a nested class that is inherited from QTcpServer?

Tags: c++, qt

My goal was to listen to some port from my program, i found this topic :

- [how to listen to a specific port in qt using QTcpSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930118/how-to-listen-to-a-specific-port-in-qt-using-qtcpsocket)

Provided as answer code obviously work but i want to provided class be nested into my own class as private member. If i type

```
class some
{

struct Server : public QTcpServer

{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Server();
    QTcpSocket server_socket;
public slots:
    void tcpReady();
    void tcpError( QAbstractSocket::SocketError error );
    bool start_listen(int port_no);
protected:
    void incomingConnection( int descriptor );
} ;
};
```

there is an error

```
Error: Class contains Q_OBJECT macro but does not inherit from QObject
 [Makefile.Debug:220: debug/moc_mainwindow.cpp] Error 1
```

but if

```
    struct some : public QObject
    { Q_OBJECT
//...
    }
```

appear error a

```
Desktop_Qt_5_12_7_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp:191: 'struct some' has no member named 'tcpReady'
  191 |         case 0: _t->tcpReady(); break;
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
```

and same error about `tcpError` and `start_listen`.
How to make this code work?

**EDIT:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class some
{

    class Server : public QTcpServer

{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Server();
    QTcpSocket server_socket;
public slots:
    void tcpReady();
    void tcpError( QAbstractSocket::SocketError error );
    bool start_listen(int port_no);
protected:
    void incomingConnection( int descriptor );
};
public:
    void test() {
        some::Server srv;
        srv.tcpReady();
    }
};

some::Server::Server(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    connect( &server_socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this, SLOT(tcpError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)) );
    connect( &server_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(tcpReady()) );
    server_socket.setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, true );
}

some::Server::~Server()
{
    server_socket.disconnectFromHost();
    server_socket.waitForDisconnected();
}

void some::Server::tcpReady()
{
    QByteArray array = server_socket.read(server_socket.bytesAvailable());
}

void some::Server::tcpError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
{
    //QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error"),tr("TCP error: %1").arg( server_socket.errorString() ) );
}

bool some::Server::start_listen(int port_no)
{
    if( !this->listen( QHostAddress::Any, port_no ) )
    {
        //QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Cannot listen to port %1").arg(port_no) );
    }
    else
        return true;
}

void some::Server::incomingConnection(int descriptor)
{
    if( !server_socket.setSocketDescriptor( descriptor ) )
    {
       // QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Socket error!") );
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    some asd;
        asd.test();
    return 0;
}
```

error :

```
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 undefined reference to `vtable for some::Server'
```

Comment: Why do not you use a class rather than a struct.

Comment: @Marco it may be class. Declaration  `class some : public QObject` both with `public:` and without change nothing . Or i am missing smth?

Comment: Note that in this particular case you don't need the `Q_OBJECT` macro since you don't declare any signals, and slots are really just normal member functions.  So no need for any moc generated code.

Comment: @G.M. ? As i undestand it _is_ always inside because `Server` is nested. And `some` contains all `Server`.

Comment: @rueodmk Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @G.M. you said "you don't need the `Q_OBJECT` macro". Dont need it inside `Server` ? No, i need it and have it as there is `public slots:` section. Dont need it inside `some`? Yes, I do not. Directly. But indirectly it is all the time there because `some` _contains_ `Server`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this with QtCreator and it compiles. As a note, QTcpServer already inherits from QObject. I have added definition of at least constructor and destructor and tcpReady directly in the declaration, have you defined the code for those signals?
By the way, I haven't used connect for slot-signal, just a test of compilation.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
class some
{
    class Server : public QTcpServer

    {

    public:
        explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0){}
        ~Server(){}
        QTcpSocket server_socket;
    public slots:
        void tcpReady() {}
        void tcpError( QAbstractSocket::SocketError error );
        bool start_listen(int port_no);
    protected:
        void incomingConnection( int descriptor );
    };
public:
    void test() {
        some::Server srv;
        srv.tcpReady();
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    some asd;
    asd.test();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Pasted all the code in the edit. It does not work for me.